# Can't cancel $interval in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a factory to long-poll, with start and stop methods. However, I can't cancel the timer. Any ideas?

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window, User, Poller) {
    Poller.start(1, $scope.session.user.user_uuid, function(result) {
      User.data.queues.montage_progress = result.field;
      if (result.field == 100) {
        Poller.stop(); //DOES NOT STOP (see below)
      }
    });
  })
```

Here is the factory:

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http, $q, $interval, $window) {
  var poll = this;
  poll.timer = null;

  poll.checkProgress = function(field, user_uuid) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/v1/poll/',
      json: true,
      params: {
        field: field,
        user_uuid: user_uuid
      }
    })
      .success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function() {
        deferred.reject("Error checking poll");
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  poll.start = function(url, user_uuid, callback) {
    poll.timer = $interval(function() {
      poll.checkProgress(url, user_uuid).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        callback(result);
      }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  poll.stop = function() {
    $interval.cancel(poll.timer);
  };
  return poll;
});
```

**EDIT:**
    Changed `$window.clearInterval` to `$interval.cancel(poll.timer);` as suggested below. But still can't cancel polling...

Comment: Is the controller code posted exactly as it is in your JavaScript file? Because if so, I think you might be missing a trailing `);` at the end of the controller definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **[cancel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#cancel)** method of `$interval`, not `clearInterval`

```
poll.stop = function() {
   $interval.cancel(poll.timer):
};
```

Comment: Thanks - it still won't stop. I checked https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval but can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Hum are you sure that your `poll.stop` function is called ?

Comment: Yeah I have a break point on it. But it is inside the callback from .start. Does that matter? Let me update the .stop code example.

Comment: And if instead of `Poller.stop();` you're directly calling `$interval.cancel(Poller.timer):` inside your controller ? Should be the same though.

Comment: that should work please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/b2ZlgUyMtWgho2y8qWzV?p=preview more likely you newer call Poller.stop()

Comment: Sorry I've confuse the people :) Yeah but that strange since the `poll.stop` seems to be called

Comment: @sss I can see your example definitely works - still can't quite see what is wrong with mine. I will study yours in more detail.

Comment: I compared it line by line - it's the same. Totally baffling.

Comment: Thank you! It was a bug in how I was calling .start - it was getting triggered dozens of times as a result of a bug elsewhere...